# Nicer Syntax for List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

I have a method:

```
public void MyMethod(params KeyValuePair<string, string>[] properties);
```

Which I invoke like:

```
MyMethod(
    new KeyValuePair("Name","Jack"), 
    new KeyValuePair("City", "New York"), 
    new KeyValuePair("Gender", "Male"), 
);
```

I would prefer a prettier syntax to invoke the method though, something similar to:

```
MyMethod({"Name","Jack"}, {"City","New York"}, {"Gender","Male"});
```

The closest I've come to that is using changing the method signature to accept a dictionary as the method argument and call :

```
MyMethod(new Dictionary<string,string>()
{
    {"Name", "Jack"},
    {"City", "New York"},
    {"Gender", "Male"},
};
```

Are there any other alternatives ?

Comment: `Dictionary<string, string>` is the best way to do it in my opinion.

Comment: What are you looking for that's cleaner than the dictionary approach? (I view that as cleaner than using a list of key/value pairs anyway, unless you want to be able to use repeated properties.)

Comment: I don't like new Dictionary<string,string>() noise...I guess I can move the dictionary initialization outside the method invocation. Just wondering if there's anything that I missed...

Comment: That looks like remarkably little noise to me. You could create your own class with a shorter name which is backed by a `Dictionary<string, string>` but *just* has an `Add(string, string)` method (and then a way of getting at them) which would turn the `new Dictionary<string, string>` into `new Properties`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accept just strings as parameters and then dynamically fill a dictionary, like this.

```
public void MyMethod(params string[] properties) 
{
    var pairs = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    for(int i = 0; i < properties.length - 1; i += 2) 
    {
        pairs.Add(properties[i], properties[i + 1]);
    }
}

MyMethod("Name", "Jack", "City", "New York", "Gender", "Male");
```

Comment: You should use `pairs.Add(properties[i], properties[i + 1])`. Else you'll get a KeyNotFoundException.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is by using two-dimensional array

```
static void PrintArray(int[,] arr)

PrintArray(new int[,] { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }, { 5, 6 }, { 7, 8 } });
```

But I prefer Dictionary approach